# How to get data from an xml inside Ext.data.Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hello i'm a new on developing mobile applications with sencha. I have made a research i google before i post here but i didn't find any solution. I'm trying to get data from an xml which has the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss
version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
>
<channel>
    <title></title>
    <link></link> 
    <description></description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <pubDate>Mon, 08 Jul 2013 13:12:39 +0000</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 08 Jul 2013 13:12:39 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <managingEditor></managingEditor>
    <item>
        <position>1</position>
        <image>img/2.png</image>
        <name>Sun</name>
        <small_desciption>dfsfsdfsdf</small_desciption>
    </item>

    <item>
        <position>2</position>
        <image>img/2.png</image>
        <name>Hot</name>
        <small_desciption>fsdfdsfsdf</small_desciption>
    </item> 
       ........
</channel>
</rss>
```

and here is my code

```
Ext.regModel('test', {
             fields: [{
                      name: 'image',
                      type: 'string'
                      }, {
                      name: 'name',
                      type: 'string'
                      }, {
                      name: 'small_desciption',
                      type: 'string'
                      }, {
                      name: 'position',
                      type: 'string',
                      }]
             });


ToolbarDemo.views.Testtab = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
                                            title: "Test",
                                            iconCls: "test",
                                            styleHtmlContent: true,
                                            style:"background-color:#FFFFFF;",                                           


                                        dockedItems: [


                                                      {
                                                      xtype: "toolbar",
                                                      title: "Test",
                                                      items : [
                                                               { xtype : 'spacer' },
                                                               // { xtype : 'spacer' },                                                             
                                                               ],

                                                      },

                                                      ],
                                             layout: {
                                             type: 'fit'
                                             },




                                             initComponent: function() {

                                              this.setLoading(true,true);
                                             var proxyUrl = 'http://mydomain/newsfeed/'

                                             var store = new Ext.data.Store({
                                                                            model: 'test',
                                                                            proxy: {
                                                                            type: 'ajax',
                                                                            url: proxyUrl,
                                                                            reader: {
                                                                            type: 'xml',
                                                                            record: 'item',
                                                                            }
                                                                            },
                                                                            datachanged: function(){
                                                                            var items = [];


                                                                            store.each(function(rec){


                                                                                       items.push({


                                                                                                  html: [
                                                                                                         '<div class="main"><div class="thumb"><div class="contain">{position}</div><div class="image"><img src="http://mydomain/{image}.jpg" width="280" height="100"></div></div><div class="mainentry"><div class="maintitle">{name}</div><div class="description">{small_desciption}</div></div></div>',


                                                                                                         ]



                                                                                                  });
                                                                                       });

                                                                            }




                                                                            });
                                             store.read();
                                             ToolbarDemo.views.Testtab.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

                                             }  });

Ext.reg('testtab', ToolbarDemo.views.Testtab);
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Extjs**,if you are getting your xml in string format,you can try this;

```
var xmlString = <channel>.....</channel> //Your xml data in string format 
parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(xmlString.body,"text/xml");
var channel = xmlMessage.childNodes[0];
if(channel){
               var image       = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               var position    = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("position")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               var name        = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               var small_desciption = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("small_desciption")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: and write this in html? like this example?http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140552-Ext.data.Store-and-XML

Comment: @George,you can use this when you are getting response in xml format and parse it respectively.In the answer is giving only the idea about getting your data from xml.